# Is it possible to login two or more with ASP.NET Membership?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, asp.net-membership

Note: This is for a MVC 3 **Intranet** app. And yes, the two or more users **MUST** be able to be logged in at the same time.

I have an app that will require two or more people to be logged in to a form at the same computer at the same time. One person will logged in to do work, the other will be logged in to acknowledge/check some of that work.

Is Membership able to handle that? If yes, how?

Comment: "same computer at the same time" - seriously... how?  What does the workstation setup look like?  Multiple monitors with three USB keyboards & mice?  Photo please if possible.

Comment: It's possible. Have one person use IE, one use FireFox and the other use Chrome :)

Comment: Actually it is possible because I had to roll my own in Webforms. It didn't use Membership however. It was a simple username and password combo, check the database, and return their userids and roles and save in viewstate. Now if you don't mind actually being helpful. That'll be great. :)

Comment: MVC has no concept of ViewState.

Answer (score 3):

They can't both be logged in to the same browser at the same time. Personally, I've never seen a web application where two users can be logged in at the same time in the same browser. I'd go with a more traditional workflow.

You'd have to have the first person log in, do the work, and log out. The work that the first user did would go into a queue for the second user. The second user would then log in, pick up the workflow from the queue, acknowledge/check the work, and then log out.